# Name for the relationship $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \sqrt{x}f(x)$

Tags: functions, symmetric-functions

In part of a larger problem, I have shown that I have a function $f$ which satisfies
\begin{align*}
f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \sqrt{x}f(x), \;\; x>0.
\end{align*}
I am just wondering if such a relationship has a specific name, as it's existence in my problem yields some rather nice results, and I would like a more elegant way to refer to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Functional equation

Comment: More precisely non-autonomous Schröder functional equation

Comment: I guess it might be called *reflection formula*, since such identity for the Jacobi $\Theta$ function can be used to prove the canonical reflection formula for the $\zeta$ function (that is my bet about the mentioned *larger problem*).

Comment: You can find a particular soluton of the functional equation by setting $f(x) = x^a$ (giving a = - 1/4).

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze: Which representation are you referencing?

Comment: @ John Snyder Sorry, I don't understand your question. I did not mention any "representation", I just said that a power ansatz leads to a solution.

Comment: @ John Snyder Here is another solution, the Jacobi Theta function Jack D'Aurizio referred to: $f(x) = \sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty } \exp \left(\pi  \left(-n^2\right) x\right) = \vartheta _3\left(0,e^{-\pi  x}\right)$. This solution is different from the power solution for all $x>0$, and it goes to unity for large positive $x$.
For details see "Jacobi identities" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function.